# Add number to each row in id column?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I need to add '000' to each row in the id colum of a Wordpress database. Those are the querys that I tried:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET ID = 000 + ID

UPDATE wp_posts SET ID = '000' + ID
```

There is no execution error but this just doesn't modified the column.

How can I do it?

Comment: What is the datatype of that `ID` column?

Comment: There is no earthly reason why you would need to do this

Comment: bigint @MayankPandeyz

Comment: If you add zero to an integer field there will be no effect so whats the reason you are you trying to do so?

Comment: ID column may be a numeric field, because of that value is not displaying like 0001.

Comment: I need to merge two tables, and the id cannot be equal. @P.Salmon

Comment: So in one table the id is bigint and in the other it's text field of some sort? It might help if you publish the table definitions.

Comment: No, the tables are exactly the same. Same columns, same datatype. @P.Salmon

Comment: In that case I'm not clear what you are trying to do. It would help if you could publish sample data from the 2 tables together with your expected outcome. I suspect this question will be closed because your question does no appear to tally with your underlying requirement.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I can see you want to merge 2 tables, but the ID is the problem for you. Try using union like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Union all should connect the tables even with duplicate values

Answer (score -1):

You can try with using below query but please take a backup for safety before trying this query.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET ID = CONCAT('000', ID);
```

Hope, This will work for you.